# rearrage an array so even values come before odds using recursion in java

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I am taking a course where I need to create a method in Java which rearranges an int array so all even integers come first and odd integers come second using recursion. The order of the integers does not matter as long as evens are fist and odds after. I can't change the method signature. I am very close as I can rearrange the array but when I run my code I get the resulting array repeated multiple times. Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.
What I get is:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45]
```

code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayClass {
  
    public static void evenBeforeOdd(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] % 2 != 0 && a[i+1] % 2 ==0) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                evenBeforeOdd(a);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] b = {10, 15, 20, 30, 25, 35, 40, 45};
//        what I want is [10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 25, 35, 45] order does not matter
        evenBeforeOdd(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?  It looks like you are getting the correct answer, just  5x in a row.

Comment: Yeah I just spent some time on it a figured what was my issue. Just a newbie here. Thanks for your reply and time.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive calls of the method `evenBeforeOdd` from the loop seem to be redundant - each time the loop starts from the initial element ignoring previous swapping, also only two adjacent elements are swapped.

This method needs to be refactored, to provide the pointers of the last odd and even elements, and the exit condition from the recursion would be `lastEven > lastOdd`: the rightmost index of the evens is greater than the leftmost index of the odds.

```java
public static void evenBeforeOdd(int[] a) {
    evenBeforeOdd(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

private static void evenBeforeOdd(int[] a, int lastEven, int firstOdd) {
    if (lastEven > firstOdd) {
        return;
    }
    while (lastEven < a.length && a[lastEven] % 2 == 0) {
        lastEven++;
    };
    
    while (firstOdd >= 0 && a[firstOdd] % 2 != 0) {
        firstOdd--;
    }
    
    if (lastEven < firstOdd) {
        int t = a[lastEven];
        a[lastEven] = a[firstOdd];
        a[firstOdd] = t;
        System.out.printf("swapping at %d and %d -> %s%n", lastEven, firstOdd, Arrays.toString(a));
        evenBeforeOdd(a, lastEven, firstOdd);
    }
}
```

Tests:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {11, 15, 20, 32, 25, 35, 44, 48},        // test 1: even length of data
    {10, 15, 20, 17, 30, 25, 35, 46, 45},    // test 2: odd length of data
    {10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 452}, // all odds
    {11, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45}, // all evens
    {11, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 452} // all evens after odds
};

for (int[] test : tests) {
    System.out.println("final: " + Arrays.toString(test));
    evenBeforeOdd(test);
    System.out.println("final: " + Arrays.toString(test));
    System.out.println("====\n");
}
```

Output:

```
start: [11, 15, 20, 32, 25, 35, 44, 48]
swapping at 0 and 7 -> [48, 15, 20, 32, 25, 35, 44, 11]
swapping at 1 and 6 -> [48, 44, 20, 32, 25, 35, 15, 11]
final: [48, 44, 20, 32, 25, 35, 15, 11]
====

start: [10, 15, 20, 17, 30, 25, 35, 46, 45]
swapping at 1 and 7 -> [10, 46, 20, 17, 30, 25, 35, 15, 45]
swapping at 3 and 4 -> [10, 46, 20, 30, 17, 25, 35, 15, 45]
final: [10, 46, 20, 30, 17, 25, 35, 15, 45]
====

start: [10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 452]
final: [10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 452]
====

start: [11, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45]
final: [11, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45]
====

start: [11, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 452]
swapping at 0 and 17 -> [452, 15, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 40, 11]
swapping at 1 and 16 -> [452, 40, 201, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 350, 15, 11]
swapping at 2 and 15 -> [452, 40, 350, 17, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 256, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 3 and 14 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 303, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 30, 17, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 4 and 13 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 25, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 18, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 5 and 12 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 18, 35, 403, 45, 10, 16, 20, 25, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 6 and 11 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 18, 20, 403, 45, 10, 16, 35, 25, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 7 and 10 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 18, 20, 16, 45, 10, 403, 35, 25, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
swapping at 8 and 9 -> [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 18, 20, 16, 10, 45, 403, 35, 25, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
final: [452, 40, 350, 256, 30, 18, 20, 16, 10, 45, 403, 35, 25, 303, 17, 201, 15, 11]
====
```

Comment: This is great Alex, thanks so much. I see what you are saying regarding the redundant recursive calls from the loop, makes sense. Thanks for your help!